# How do I split a duration of time into hourly intervals in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

This is my table.

| Location | Date | Employee | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2021-01-01 | A1 | 10 | 15 |
| A | 2021-01-01 | A1 | 15 | 16 |
| B | 2021-01-01 | B1 | 16 | 21 |
| C | 2021-01-01 | C1 | 11 | 15 |

Here is the expected output:

| Location | Date | Employee | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2021-01-01 | A1 | 10 | 15 |
| A | 2021-01-01 | A1 | 11 | 15 |
| A | 2021-01-01 | A1 | 12 | 15 |
| A | 2021-01-01 | A1 | 13 | 15 |
| A | 2021-01-01 | A1 | 14 | 15 |
| A | 2021-01-01 | A1 | 15 | 15 |
| A | 2021-01-01 | A1 | 15 | 16 |
| A | 2021-01-01 | A1 | 16 | 16 |
| B | 2021-01-01 | B1 | 16 | 21 |
| B | 2021-01-01 | B1 | 17 | 21 |
| B | 2021-01-01 | B1 | 18 | 21 |
| B | 2021-01-01 | B1 | 19 | 21 |
| B | 2021-01-01 | B1 | 20 | 21 |
| B | 2021-01-01 | B1 | 21 | 21 |
| C | 2021-01-01 | C1 | 11 | 15 |
| C | 2021-01-01 | C1 | 12 | 15 |
| C | 2021-01-01 | C1 | 13 | 15 |
| C | 2021-01-01 | C1 | 14 | 15 |
| C | 2021-01-01 | C1 | 15 | 15 |

Please help me how to split like this in BigQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT * EXCEPT(t) REPLACE(t AS start)
  FROM my_table, UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(start, `end`)) t
 ORDER BY Location, start;
```

###### Query results:

```
+----------+------------+----------+-------+-----+
| Location |    Date    | Employee | start | end |
+----------+------------+----------+-------+-----+
| A        | 2021-01-01 | A1       |    10 |  15 |
| A        | 2021-01-01 | A1       |    11 |  15 |
| A        | 2021-01-01 | A1       |    12 |  15 |
| A        | 2021-01-01 | A1       |    13 |  15 |
| A        | 2021-01-01 | A1       |    14 |  15 |
| A        | 2021-01-01 | A1       |    15 |  15 |
| A        | 2021-01-01 | A1       |    15 |  16 |
| A        | 2021-01-01 | A1       |    16 |  16 |
| B        | 2021-01-01 | B1       |    16 |  21 |
| B        | 2021-01-01 | B1       |    17 |  21 |
| B        | 2021-01-01 | B1       |    18 |  21 |
| B        | 2021-01-01 | B1       |    19 |  21 |
| B        | 2021-01-01 | B1       |    20 |  21 |
| B        | 2021-01-01 | B1       |    21 |  21 |
| C        | 2021-01-01 | C1       |    11 |  15 |
| C        | 2021-01-01 | C1       |    12 |  15 |
| C        | 2021-01-01 | C1       |    13 |  15 |
| C        | 2021-01-01 | C1       |    14 |  15 |
| C        | 2021-01-01 | C1       |    15 |  15 |
+----------+------------+----------+-------+-----+
```

Comment: wow!! I never thought it could make it this short... you saved my life. thank you sooo much jaytiger :)